# italicized Words inside fpdf cell

Tags: cell, fpdf

is there any way i can italicized a certain words inside $this->Cell(0,3,'Hello, my name is (italicized) John Doe.',0,1,'C');
I just need to emphasized the name 'John Doe' and not the whole sentence. 
Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately **you can't do that** directly with only FPDF functions. What you need here is to code a new function wich recreate `Cell()` with some new parameters...

But wait... **someone already did that!**

It's here: [FPDF Add-On by Pascal Morin](http://www.fpdf.org/fr/script/script23.php)

It's such a great job that you don't even need something else! :)